# Do I need to install Tomcat and MySQL on the Linux server to deploy Grails app?

Tags: grails, web-deployment

My Grails app is based on

- Gradle with Grails 2.4.4,
- Tomcat plugin 7.0.55,
- and MySQL plugin(mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29).

Do I need to install Tomcat on the server?

Do I need to install MySQL on the server?

Both Tomcat and MySQL are not installed on dev environment(on my PC), but it seems working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Container

While all the other answers pointed out, that you need already a container (which of course is true) there is also the option to use one of the "standalone" plugins (like e.g. https://grails.org/plugin/standalone).  This will package your app as a fat jar, where the container and your app are part of a jar, that you simply run by `java -jar myapp.jar` (of course your would integrate that into your regular startup scripts on the server).

This is in general no bad option, since many WAR-deployed apps don't need any of the full blown container features anyway and you would be able to configure everything in place for **your** workload and don't have to compromise for all running wars (or your ops team).  On the downside, if there is a security problem etc. with the container you would have to roll a new jar.

/With grails 3, which uses Spring Bootstrap, this even is a default option, since the preferred way of deploying.  Spring Boot 1.2 supports Tomcat, Jetty, and Undertow by default./

#### Database

You can use a MySQL from "somewhere" else.  But this is nitpicking, since you really need a MySQL **somewhere** (BTW: you really should start using MySQL also for your dev env, or you will be in for a few surprises once you put your stuff over to production).

Also be aware, that you can also keep using your H2 (see your datasource config) with files.  This is an OK option (that saves you from installing a DB server) for small amounts of data you are storing and also there are other free database servers like PostgreSQL.

Comment: " _BTW: you really should start using MySQL also for your dev env, or you will be in for a few surprises once you put your stuff over to production_ "

**excellent** advice, I ran into a large number of problems when I went to deploy regarding my constraint logic, table names, and the like that weren't a problem when I would `run-app` with the default H2 in memory db.

Comment: @TedDelezene yet alone for your liquidbase migrations.  My first bet to get MySQL wrong would be the use of the wrong dialect. And it's all downhill from there ;P

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have to install mysql and tomcat on the server.

During development you run grails from console, so you dont need tomcat as it will use embedded tomcat but still you need to have mysql installed, if you want to use mysql.

But on production, you create a war of your app using 'grails war command' and you deploy this war to a web container just like any other war, so you need tomcat and you will need mysql installed too.

Answer (score 0):

In one word answer is 'Yes'.

Fact is when you are in development environment grails uses as an embedded tomcat server provided by the 'Apache Tomcat plugin' which version corresponds to grails version.

You've not installed mysql and you claimed 'it seems working'. That's funny! But it's not mysql who is working without being installed(!), rather it's also an integrated database provided by the 'H2 Database Plugin'.

So, when you'll deploy your grails app in Linux or another server certainly you need a tomcat server to handle user request to that app and a database where your data will be saved.